# how to get the geolocation of a click on a bing map in C#

Tags: c#, bing-maps

is it possible to get the geolocation of the point where i clicked on a bing `Map` in c#?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research? Letting people know what you have tried/researched makes it more likely you'll receive information you don't already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, since you're in WinRT in C#, you're using the Bing Maps Windows Store App control.
Add the map into your XAML markup:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Win8PublicApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:m="using:Bing.Maps">
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <m:Map Name="MyMap" Credentials="YOURKEY"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Then you can do this to add pushpin where you have clicked:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.MyMap.PointerPressedOverride += MyMap_PointerPressedOverride;
}

void MyMap_PointerPressedOverride(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Bing.Maps.Location l = new Bing.Maps.Location();
    this.MyMap.TryPixelToLocation(e.GetCurrentPoint(this.MyMap).Position, out l);
    Bing.Maps.Pushpin pushpin = new Bing.Maps.Pushpin();
    pushpin.SetValue(Bing.Maps.MapLayer.PositionProperty, l);
    this.MyMap.Children.Add(pushpin);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Bing Maps API makes this pretty easy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

         var map = null;         

         function GetMap()
         {
            // Initialize the map
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"),
                         {credentials:"Bing Maps Key"}); 

            //Add handler for the map click event.
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', displayLatLong);


         }

          function displayLatLong(e) {
              if (e.targetType == "map") {
                  var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                  var loc = e.target.tryPixelToLocation(point);
                  document.getElementById("textBox").value= loc.latitude + ", " + loc.longitude;

              }
          }

      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
      <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div><br>
      <b>Click the map to display the coordinate values at that point.</b><br>
      Latitude, Longitude:       
      <input id='textBox' type="text" style="width:250px;"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Source: [Bing Maps API on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508988.aspx)

Comment: c# and winrt not javascript

Comment: You can use JS in Windows RT apps.  Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx

What does your app look like now?

Comment: I don't think it related to its needs since he asked for C# application.